# Getting realtime updates for document upon its creation?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have an angular app utilizing cloud firestore. I have created a function in a service that gets a users rating from the 'ratings' collection. Every rating is stored in this collection and the documents id is the user id combined with the movies id.

```
getUserRating(movie_id) {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db.collection('ratings').doc(user.uid + '_' + movie_id).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

And I execute this code in ngOnInit() within my component.

```
this.ratingService.getUserRating(this.release.id).subscribe(doc => {
    this.userRating = doc['rating'];
    this.ratingSliderValue = this.userRating;
}));
```

The issue with this code is that it does respond to changes if the document already exists, but if a user sets the initial rating for the movie it doesn't execute because the document does not previously exist. The page has to be reloaded. Any suggestions on how to get this working properly?

Comment: You should get changes for documents that do not previously exist.  Are you sure that you're not just subscribing to the empty list in the else block, which will never change?

Comment: I ran console.log under the else statement and it never returned. Im not sure what else could be causing this then.

Comment: Solved. This occured because I was not handling undefined data. I added "if (doc) {}" and this seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Good to know that you solved the issue by yourself @KevinShiflett. Please do Consider adding the solution to an answer to your post and accept it. That way if someone else in the community is facing the same issue you faced they can refer easily to your solution, plus this will help improving your reputation on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this occured because I was not handling an undefined response. valueChanges returns an unkown observable and setting doc['rating'] threw an undefined error. Wrapping the code with if (doc) {} solved this issue and listened for updates.

```
this.ratingService.getUserRating(this.release.id).subscribe(doc => {
    if (doc) {
       this.userRating = doc['rating'];
       this.ratingSliderValue = this.userRating;
    }
}));
```